# How to refresh the list returned by Pyside.QNetworkProxyFactory.systemProxyForQuery()?

Tags: python, pyside

OK, i'm using this function to get the system proxy settings in python. Everything works fine, but the list returned does not change if the system proxy settings change during the runtime. I need to restart python and the program to make the list refresh. It is either an issue with QT or Python. Is there any way to make the list refresh without restarting python or the program?

```
while True:
    p = QtNetwork.QNetworkProxyFactory.systemProxyForQuery(QtNetwork.QNetworkProxyQuery('http://www.google.com'))[0]
    print(p.hostName(), p.port())
    sleep(0.5)
```

This always returns the same proxy settings and does not change when the system proxy settings change, until, i restart the code, then it grabs the new settings.